# Why do I get strange result when & (anding) bits on __int64 variable?

Tags: c++, 64-bit

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void printbinary3(T num){
   for(int i = sizeof(T) * 8 - 1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
      if((1 << i) &  num)
         cout << "1";
      else
         cout << "0";   
   }
   cout << endl;
}

int main ()
{
   char a = 1;
   short b = 1;
   int c = 1;
   long d = 1;
   __int64 e = 1;
   unsigned __int64 f = 1;

   printbinary3(a);
   printbinary3(b);
   printbinary3(c);
   printbinary3(d);
   printbinary3(e);
   printbinary3(f);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
00000001
0000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001
```

When compiling I get this error for the unsigned __int64 variable - f.

```
1> : warning C4334: '<<' : result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 
     64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?)
1>   xx.cpp(66) : see reference to function template instantiation 
     'void printbinary3<unsigned __int64>(T)' being compiled
```

Why am I not seeing

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

as the output for the 64 bit integer?

Angus

Comment: You are anding a 32 bit int with a 64 bit int. Try for(T i = sizeof ...

Comment: Just a note I changed for check slightly to cater for unsigned numbers:  for(T i = sizeof(T) * 8 - 1; i >= 0 && i != ~0; --i)   Possibly not best solution, but it works.

Comment: Don't use `T` for the running variable `i`, since `T` might be unsigned.  `i >= 0` will always be true and `i != ~0` is kind of hacky.  You could also do:  `for (T mask = T(1) << (sizeof(T) * 8 - 1); mask != 0; mask >>= 1) if (mask & num) { ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `printbinary3` function:

```
void printbinary3(T num){
   for(int i = sizeof(T) * 8 - 1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
      if((1 << i) &  num)
```

Here, you are creating a literal `1` of type `int`, which most probably is 32 bit.  If `T = __int64`, you will shift it for too many bits, leading to an overflow and the warning.

Instead of using implicit `int`, explicitely create a `T` instead:

```
      if((T(1) << i) &  num)
```

This should fix the warning and the output.

Comment: Unfortunately, that change does not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure?  I compiled and tested the code both with Visual C++ and GCC and it *did* fix it!

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, yes changing to T(1) does correct issue.  Perhaps I didn't recompile correctly.  Actually, this is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Read the warnings and fix the code.

In C++0x or as an extension in g++'s current C++ implementation , 64 bit unsigned integer literals need an `ull` postfix: `50ull`. 64 bit unsigned integer need be declared `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Thanks, changing to:  if((1ull << i) &  num)  fixed the problem.  I need to think through why now :)

Comment: C++11 also has the optional uint64_t in cstdint

Comment: @user619818: The why is simply in the Standard, i.e. it's the way it works in C++. Actually, it is a feature, considering that C++ assumes you to know what you are doing. The standard basically says: 1 fits into an int, therefore it is an int. Then, you are shifting something leftwards that is an int.